# How to Fill In Text Boxes Within a Word Reference Document Using Quarto

Tags: r, ms-word, formatting, markdown, quarto

I am trying to insert text into text boxes that are already defined in my Word reference document using Quarto. I am unsure how to preserve these text boxes when I render my Word document from Quarto. Further, I am also unsure how to assign certain text to certain text boxes (there are several of them scattered throughout the reference document).